# Regex to remove the character immediately after number

Tags: regex

I want to remove a substring and number from the string.
For example:

1. AB1 Line 01B
2. CD12 Line 21
3. AE2 Line 12a

should return

1. AB
2. CD
3. AE  respectively

Currently, I'm using 'Line|[0-9]' regex, which can match everything except the character immediately after the string ('B' in 01B).
What changes should I make?
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `\s*(?:Line|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)\s*` work? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WOO8ou/2).

Comment: Can you show more relevant data, or at least more diverse. As per the current samples you could just match [`\d.*`](https://regex101.com/r/O91jS3/1) and replace with nothing.

Comment: Where are you running this regex replacement, could you please share the relevant code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew \s*(?:Line|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)\s* this regex worked. I'm using this in a SQL query. regexp_replace(column_name, 'Line|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*', '') is the exact code I use. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sql
regexp_replace(column_name, 'Line|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*', '')
```

If you wish to also remove whitespace on both ends, you may match whitespaces with `[[:space:]]*` (or `\s*`, where `\` might need doubling):

```sql
regexp_replace(column_name, '[[:space:]]*(Line|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)[[:space:]]*', '')
regexp_replace(column_name, '\\s*(Line|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)\\s*', '')
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(` - start of a group:

  - `Line` - a fixed string
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
  - `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more letters
- `)` - end of the group
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "AB1 Line 01B"
var b = a.replace(/\d.*/g, "")
console.log(b)
```